# How to change scrollwheelspeed in Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scrolling, xubuntu

Two things I hate about Xubuntu: Mouse is crazy fast in the slowest setting, and the scrollwheel is crazy-slow, scrolling only 2 lines of text per scroll, and this cannot be changed *at all*.

For the mouse speed, there are some bash-tricks you can add to **.profile** like so:

```
xinput --set-prop `xinput --list --short | grep -m1 "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" | cut -f2 | cut -d= -f2` "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
```

Is there a (similar?) trick to make that scrollwheel useful again?